# file_put_contents - remote file create

Tags: php

Can I create/write on a file on another host & domain with file_put_contents() OR fwrite()?

If I can, what permissions and other property should set on that host?

Thanks ..

Answer (score 6):

check this out from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php#101408

To upload file from your localhost to any FTP server. 
pease note 'ftp_chdir' has been used instead of putting direct remote file path....in ftp_put ...remoth file should be only file name

```
<?php 
$host = '*****'; 
$usr = '*****'; 
$pwd = '**********';         
$local_file = './orderXML/order200.xml'; 
$ftp_path = 'order200.xml'; 
$conn_id = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die ("Cannot connect to host");      
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 
ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd) or die("Cannot login"); 
// perform file upload 
ftp_chdir($conn_id, '/public_html/abc/'); 
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $local_file, FTP_ASCII); 
if($upload) { $ftpsucc=1; } else { $ftpsucc=0; } 
// check upload status: 
print (!$upload) ? 'Cannot upload' : 'Upload complete'; 
print "\n"; 
// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id); 
?>
```

Comment: This function is transferring files but file does not open on new server properly. So what can be the solution for this?

Comment: Fixed it by changing the line $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $local_file, FTP_ASCII);  to $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $local_file, FTP_BINARY);

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function similar to PHP file_put_contents() which is writing to a FTP server:

```
function ftp_file_put_contents($remote_file, $file_string)
{
    // FTP login
    $ftp_server="my-ftp-server.com"; 
    $ftp_user_name="my-ftp-username"; 
    $ftp_user_pass="my-ftp-password";

    // Create temporary file
    $local_file=fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
    fwrite($local_file, $file_string);
    rewind($local_file);       

    // Create FTP connection
    $ftp_conn=ftp_connect($ftp_server); 

    // FTP login
    @$login_result=ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

    // FTP upload
    if($login_result) $upload_result=ftp_fput($ftp_conn, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_ASCII);

    // Error handling
    if(!$login_result or !$upload_result)
    {
        echo('FTP error: The file could not be written on the remote server.');
    }

    // Close FTP connection
    ftp_close($ftp_conn);

    // Close file handle
    fclose($local_file);
}

// Usage
ftp_file_put_contents('my-file.txt', 'This string will be written to the remote file.');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `file_put_contents` specifically, you have to use a [stream context](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) for a protocol the remote server accepts for uploading. For instance, if the server is configured to allow PUT requests, you could create an HTTP context and send the appropriate method and content to the server. Another option would be to setup an FTPs context.

There is an example in the [comments for `file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php#101408) on how to use it with a stream context for FTP. Note that the used ftp://user:pass@host URI scheme is transmitting the user credentials in cleartext.

[Additional examples](http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/upgrading+php+5/Chapter+8.+Streams+Wrappers+and+Filters/8.3+Wrapper+Details/)